# Odoo Pipeline report include a field from related model

Tags: python, report, odoo, odoo-10

In Odoo Opportunity Report I would like to add field `customer` from res.partner.

I created addon (which installed, and does other things besides, so I am sure that addon works) in which I have inherited from https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/crm/report/crm_opportunity_report.py .

And added a field

```
customer = fields.Boolean('Customer', related='partner_id.customer', readonly=True)
```

But field Customer doesn't appear in report when I click '+' in Reports->Pipeline.

What did I miss?

Comment: How did you inherit `crm.opportunity.report` exactly? Can you provide the code? My first guess: you forgot to extend the postgres database view, odoo is using for those reporting feature. (in your example in the `init()`)

Comment: did you check that the customer field exits in your model, check that in setting?? related field can be used in reports

Comment: @CZoellner thank You. You are right, I have not added (intentionally :)) that field to the view, I was hoping for some magic (that it will work somehow without modifying the view) :D.

Comment: @Cherif yes, there is a `boolean` field `customer` in model res_partner (and in table res_partner). :)

Comment: @Chief There is that field https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/379b7359621fd1239b0b4ae9f1fbc2954e574e95/odoo/addons/base/res/res_partner.py#L171

Comment: @CZoellner after I added `is_customer = fields.Boolean('Is customer', readonly=True)` and modified a view creation `CREATE VIEW crm_opportunity_report AS (
    SELECT
        <...>omitted<...>
        rp.customer as is_customer
    FROM
        "crm_lead" c                        
        LEFT JOIN "res_partner" rp ON rp.id = c.partner_id
        <...>omitted<...>                
    GROUP BY c.id, stage.name, is_customer` I get the value. :)

Comment: Cool, i saw your following question, but don't see any mistakes in it :-/

Comment: @CZoellner, anyway Thank You :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to define a field. Odoo reporting is working on database views. So by adding a new field, you have to change the view, too. Normally or in newer versions Odoo has good extendable view definitions by using the `init()`. In your example it's the old "bad to extend" view definition, so you have to override the whole `init`.